# Slide Javascript error

Tags: javascript, slider

Estoy siguiendo el ejemplo de https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryit.asp?filename=tryw3css_slideshow_self para hacer un slider de imagenes, con la diferencia que la parte Javascript la tengo en un arhivo aparte, para que no este en el mismo HTML.

Sin embargo el problema es que al ejecutar mi archivo me sale el error

```
TypeError: x[(slideIndex - 1)] is undefined
```

Nota, copie textualmente el ejemplo que puse en el link con mi archivo, pero no se que cambio tendria que hacer en mi fichero javascript para evitar este error

Answer (score 2):

Si tienes el mismo ejemplo que has pasado por el enlace, pero el `JavaScript` lo tienes en otro archivo y no en el `HTML`, tan solo debes llamar a ese archivo `js` desde el `HTML`

```
 <script src="myscripts.js"></script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>W3.CSS</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">

<script src="myscripts.js"></script> //LLamada al archivo JS

<style>
.mySlides {display:none;}
</style>
<body>

<h2 class="w3-center">Manual Slideshow</h2>

<div class="w3-content w3-display-container">
  <img class="mySlides" src="img_snowtops.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides" src="img_lights.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides" src="img_mountains.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides" src="img_forest.jpg" style="width:100%">

  <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-display-left" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</button>
  <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-display-right" onclick="plusDivs(1)">&#10095;</button>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**JS:**

```
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length}
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
}
```

Espero que te sirva!

Answer (score 2):

Asumiendo que has importado bien el código parece que JS no encuentra los sliders o el slider X. Para que JS pueda identificar los objetos .mySlides del DOM necesitas ejecutar el script una vez se haya cargado todo el documento HTML.

Si ejecutas el script desde la etiqueta head te devolverá un error.

La estructura tu archivo *.html debería ser algo así:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>W3.CSS</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<style>
    .mySlides {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
<body>
    <h2 class="w3-center">Manual Slideshow</h2>
    <div class="w3-content w3-display-container">
        <img class="mySlides" src="img_snowtops.jpg" style="width:100%">
        <img class="mySlides" src="img_lights.jpg" style="width:100%">
        <img class="mySlides" src="img_mountains.jpg" style="width:100%">
        <img class="mySlides" src="img_forest.jpg" style="width:100%">
        <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-display-left" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</button>
        <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-display-right" onclick="plusDivs(1)">&#10095;</button>
    </div>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script> --> Directorio js con archivos *.js
</body>
</html>
```